# Trying to embed Youtube Video using URL link with PHP & Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, youtube, prepared-statement

I have the following method I'm using for embedding a Youtube video on my page:

```
$body = strip_tags($body); //removes html tags 
// $body = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, $body);
$check_empty = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $body); //Deletes all spaces 

if($check_empty != "") {

    $body_array = preg_split("/\s+/", $body);

    foreach ($body_array as $key => $value) {

        if(strpos($value, "www.youtube.com/watch?v=") !== false) {

            $link = preg_split("!&!", $value);
            $value = preg_replace("!watch\?v=!", "embed/", $link[0]);
            $value = "<br><iframe frameborder=\'0\' style=\'visibility:visible; border: 1px solid #fff;\' width=\'590\' height=\'315\' src=\'" . $value ."\'></iframe>";
            $body_array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $body = implode(" ", $body_array);
```

This is what I'm using to input into the database:

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->con, "INSERT INTO posts VALUES('', '$body', '$added_by', '$user_to', '$date_added', 'no', 'no', '0', '$imageName')");
$returned_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->con);
```

When I change the query to a prepare statement like so:

```
$no = 'no';
$zero = 0;
$empty = '';

$query = $this->con->stmt_init();
$query->prepare("INSERT INTO posts VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query->bind_param('issssssis', $empty, $body, $added_by, $user_to, $date_added, $no, $no, $zero, $imageName);
$query->execute();
$returned_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->con);
$query->close();
```

My Youtube links no longer work. With the regular statement they are entering the dB like this:

```
<br><iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/0EqINqnEa-Y'></iframe><br>
```

With the prepared statement I'm getting this in the dB and then obviously an error on the page.

```
<br><iframe frameborder=\'0\' style=\'visibility:visible; border: 1px solid #fff;\' width=\'590\' height=\'315\' src=\'https://www.youtube.com/embed/f_WqYtj1Wik\'></iframe>
```

Any thoughts on how to correct this?

Comment: I realize that, but do these not need to be escaped?  The idea is for the $body values to be safe going into the db.

Comment: They should not have been escaped to begin with - not in _that place_. The data should have been treated with the _appropriate_ function to make it safe for insertion into a SQL query - that would have been `mysqli_real_escape_string`. But with prepared statements that properly use placeholders and then bind the values to those afterwards, that step of escaping the data is not necessary any more - _because_ the statement syntax and the data are not mixed together in the first place.

Comment: You can see that with the previous query I was using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, but I commented it out when I switched to prepared statement.  But the `mysqli_real_escape_string` alone without the treatment of the inserted data displays nothing.  It needs to be escaped in order to display.

Comment: But yes on the prepared, it's not necessary nor' is the `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: _“But the mysqli_real_escape_string alone without the treatment of the inserted data displays nothing.”_ - that’s because you applied it to the wrong value to begin with … You only applied it to `$body`, but then you put that into a larger HTML string in `$value`. _That one_ itself contained characters that needed escaping, so _that one_ is the one that `mysqli_real_escape_string` should have been applied to.

Comment: @Raylene May I recommend that you not store a big bulky portion of HTML in your database?  Not only will it fill your database table with mostly redundant data, but if you only save the video id string, then you can very simply manage the displaying of the data in the future (in case you want to resize `<iframe>` or something.  If you show your raw input, I would like to see if I can show you a much more direct way to extract the video ids and refine your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your question to show your raw input data, I'll try to provide a cleaner way for you to extract the youtube urls.  Until then, here is my recommended code starting from an isolated url string:

```
$url = "www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EqINqnEa-Y";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $array);
$video = $array['v'];

if (!$stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO posts VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), 'no', 'no', 0, ?)")) {  // NULL for AUTOINCREMENT
    echo "Stmt Preparation Error"; // $this->con->error
} elseif (!$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $video, $added_by, $user_to, $imageName)) {  // store video id, not html
    echo "Param Binding Error"; // $stmt->error
} elseif (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Stmt Execution Error"; // $stmt->error
} else {
    $returned_id = $this->con->insert_id;  // maintain object-oriented syntax
    $stmt->close();
}
```

- `parse_url()` with the `PHP_URL_QUERY` flag will generate a string from the url query (everything after `?`).
- `parse_str()` will convert the query string into an array.  `$array` is the nominated variable to receive the converted data.
- You can access the video id via the `v` key from `$array`.
- I have removed the `stmt_init()` call because I prefer to make fewer calls in my script.
- Because it is only truly necessary to placeholders and binding on insecure and potentially unstable values, I will encourage you to simplify your prepared statement.

  - Hardcode the `no` and `0` values.
  - Use `NULL` for the AUTOINCREMENT column.
  - As I said in my comment, best practice would indicate that you should only store the video id in your db table for reduced memory usage and improved data maintainability.
  - Use `NOW()` for the `date_added` (assuming you are storing a DATETIME stamp).
- I've built in some conditionals for convenient debugging.
- Be sure to maintain object-oriented syntax when fetching the `insert_id`.

Comment: ...thanks for this, sorry was travelling.  Yes I understand that up-votes are repayment and I really appreciate this answer.  You are correct, storing all of the html in the dB as I've done is redundant, when all you need is `v=` .  Much more efficient.

Comment: The challenge with this is when I call it using a separate load posts function.  I'll have to muck with that to make this work as intended.

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying, but I assure you it will be worth it to implement my snippet into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing it all wrong! You don't need all of that nonsense in your DB, only the video ID:

```
<?php

$body = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2v5jh9hy-Y';
$body = parse_url($body);
parse_str($body['query'], $query);

// This is what should go in your DB
$video = $query['v'];

// And here's how you output it
echo '<br><iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $video . '"></iframe><br>';
```

Check it out here: https://3v4l.org/kdAq4

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have a separate function for loading posts that makes this format incompatible.  I could place an if statement in there to display the iframe if this is what's being called from the dB, but my way just seems easier.